# how to enter series of numbers in a table column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to have values in a column in particular series

```
10100
10200
10300
.
.
.
.
11000
11100
11200
.
.
```

How to do this ? I think while loop would be used

```
insert into mytable(col_name)
select <>
```

Comment: I believe you could actually use an identity column and set the increment parameter to 100, but depending on the context of what you plan to do, might have limitations: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186775.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this:

```
WITH Temp
AS
(
  SELECT digit
  FROM (VALUES(0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9)) AS temp(digit)
), Nums
AS
(
  SELECT t3.digit * 100 + t2.digit * 10 + t1.digit + 1  AS id
  FROM         TEMP AS t1
  CROSS JOIN TEMP AS t2
  CROSS JOIN TEMP AS t3
)
SELECT 
  n = 10100 + (id - 1) * 100
from nums
ORDER BY n;
```

### [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/11151)

---

### How this works?

This query will give you 1000 rows for the sequence you are looking for, which is called [*Arithmetic progression*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression), and in your sequence the nth term of the sequence is given by `A + (n - 1) * d`. In your sequence: `a = 10100` the first number, the starting number, `d = 100` which is the seed.

- First, I used an anchor query which generate 10 numbers, (note that this syntax is new to SQL Server 2008),
- then I cross joined it with itself 3 times giving me 10<sup>3</sup> rows = 1000 rows I used them to generate 1000 numbers of this sequence based on the rule: each n number = `A + (n - 1) * d` , if you need more cross join it with it self more times.

You can then insert them into a new table, just do `INSERT INTO SELECT`, instead of just `SELECT`.

---

**Note that:** You might need to use [`IDENTITY`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933196%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) column instead of all this stuff, using it you can define a starting value and a seeding value, then it will be incremented automatically, see this article:

- [Understanding Identity Columns](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/understanding-identity-columns)

Answer (score 2):

Please try this:

```
DECLARE @table as TABLE(NUM bigint)
declare @var bigint
set @var=10100
while @var<11200
begin
    insert into @table values (@var)
    set @var=@var+100
end

select * from @table
```

Comment: Loop through 1 to number of rows in table…